# Critical section: be sure that this method is executed by only 1 thread

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, locking, critical-section

lets make it simple:
normally update() is executed by multiple threads.
once this is true if(!isSplit && users.size() >= Constants.SPLIT_THRESHOLD) i want that no one is executiong the update() method when the split() functions is celled.

```
public class Cell {
    private ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, User> users;
    private ConcurrentHashMap<Long, Cell> subCells;
    private boolean isSplit;
    private Lock splitLock;

    public Set<Integer> update(User user){

        //code executed by 1 thread
        if(!isSplit && users.size() >= Constants.SPLIT_THRESHOLD)
        {
            splitLock.lock();
            {
                try
            {
                    split();
                    isSplit = true;
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally
                {
                    splitLock.unlock();
                }
            }
        }

        // code executed by multiple threads
        // on users hashmap
    }
    private void merge(){}
    private void split(){}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not in a position to tell you if your code is currently getting the locking / synchronization correct.

However, under normal circumstances, I'd use a primitive object mutex for something like this:

```
private final Object splitLock = new Object();

// Use it like this ...
synchronized (splitLock) {
    split();
}
```

AFAIK, there is no performance advantage in using a `ReentrantLock` over a primitive object mutex.  I'd only recommend using this class if you are going to make use of features that primitive object mutexes don't support;

Comment: Thx, i will keep in mind using this.
But in this project i have to use a reentrant lock because i can test if the lock is aquired or not.

Answer (score 4):

A general pattern, when locking for write/update, is to acquire the lock first, then check your conditions (that are modified by the write/update), then write.

```
lock
if(x) {
    write/update
}
unlock
```

Contrast that with this, which is analogous to the code you have posted:

```
if(x) {
    lock
    write/update
    unlock
}
```

x can evaluate to true for thread-1, meanwhile thread-2 executes a write/update causing x to evaluate to false, but thread-1 is already inside the condition, and will execute a write/update anyway.  fail.

**UPDATE**: Responding to updated question.

Check out the javadoc for **ReentrantReadWriteLock**.

You probably want to isolate your split() method with a write lock (only one thread can acquire), and the remainder of your update method with a read lock (multiple threads can acquire, so long as no one has the write lock).

Comment: hi, if i lock the whole code in the update method() this code will be executed by 1 thread at time (anyway i simplified the question)

Comment: you are right, infact in my split method i check again if(isSplit) and return immidiatly if it is true.
I dont use your first solution because i want that multiple threads can execute update() in particular the code under the first if.
But when i split i want that only 1 thread is inside update().